# Firebase Cloud function Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send notification using Firebase function. I have made a function where is a time if time over it will send a notification. I already made a function but it showing internal error what I can do now?
I have used here axios for hit the firebase cloud messaging api.

```
const { setGlobalOptions } = require("firebase-functions/v2/options");
const { onRequest } = require("firebase-functions/v2/https");
const logger = require("firebase-functions/logger");


// Set the maximum instances to 10 for all functions
setGlobalOptions({ maxInstances: 10 });

// Import necessary modules
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const axios = require('axios');

// Initialize Firebase Admin SDK
admin.initializeApp();

// Define your Cloud Function
exports.readRealtimeDatabase = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {

    try {
        // Get a reference to the database
        const db = admin.database();

        // Path to the data you want to read in the realtime database
        const dataRef = db.ref('/usersToken');

        // Read the data
        const snapshot = await dataRef.once('value');

        // Extract the data from the snapshot
        const data1 = snapshot.val();

        const obj = Object.values(data1);

        const tokens = [];
        obj.forEach(el => {
            console.log({ el })
            const date = new Date((el.timestamp));
            const currentDate = new Date();
            if (date < currentDate) {
                tokens.push(el.fcmToken);
            }
        });

        if (!tokens.length) {
            return;
        }

        await sendNotification(tokens, {
            "title": "Start new mining session",
            "body": "Your money is waiting for you start mining right away."
        });

        // Send the data as a response
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error reading data:', error);
        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error: ', error);
    }

    const sendNotification = async (tokens, notification) => {
        try {
            console.log({ tokens })
            const data = {
                registration_ids: tokens,
                notification
            };

            const headers = {
                'Authorization': 'key=AAAAu6y0yqU:APA91bHG5FZjTMesMN0GVFFTNPTk94T_px80E8M7wE7hZZ9f8h9NRCI2uE0Ci_xHmNAQr77-b7foa-ijoZ2-kMKw8EirlcBASVjjjGxHO0DP0ph82eVV9M0qL2unpoAXwo1piZXs_zO9',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }

            const response = axios.post('https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send', data, { headers });
            console.log(response.data);
            res.json(response.data)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
});
```

this my function. so how can i solve it?

Comment: Your question should contain the exact error message, logs, and any other information that you have as you've debugged this so far.  Just saying "it showing internal error" isn't enough for us to be able to help. I suggest reviewing this [checklist](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/checklist) for steps to make your question more complete.

Comment: I have tried to see log I don’t get it. Where it is